Avoid animation when updating unfocused indicator colour based on a condition
I am new to Jetpack compose and stuck in an issue where I need to change the unfocusesIndicatorColor of an OutlinedTextBox based on a condition when focus is changed. Following is my code.
colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors().copy(
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color(LocalContext.current.colorAttribute(R.attr.colorTextInputHighlight)),
                focusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = if (text.isNotEmpty()) Color(LocalContext.current.color(R.color.black)) else Color(
                    LocalContext.current.color(R.color.brand_outline)
                ),
                errorContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                errorIndicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
            )

It is working but with a weird dark animation that is not smooth and displays as there is some glitch in the screen. It could be due to the abrupt transition between the
unfocusedIndicatorColor and the focusedIndicatorColor
Is there a way to avoid the dark animation  How can this be handled as this is a business requirement.
P.S it works without any dark animation if put a color directly instead of conditional color in unfocusedIndicatorColor
